# Por qué mi app no muestra el icono cuando la descargo de Google Play?

Tags: java, android, google-play

He desarrollado una app la cual ya está subida a la tienda Google Play. Para elegir el icono de mi app lo hice con new Image Asset y he seleccionado la imagen del icono. Cuando probé mi app en mi dispositivo funcionaba bien pero una vez subida la app a Google Play, cuando descargo la app el icono no aparece. (Lo he configurado con File/new Image Asset). Agradecería su ayuda.

```
    #AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Linterna"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-2703074771097768~5500736552"/>
    </application>

</manifest>

    #build.gradle
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Linterna"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-2703074771097768~5500736552"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

No sé qué es lo que funciona mal, porque cuando hago File/New/Image Asset me aparece el ícono de la app como si estuviera bien configurado pero cuando bajo la app de Google Play no se ve el ícono en el dispositivo

Comment: agrega tu AndroidManifest.xml y tu build.gradle para revisar la configuración, recuerda que debes aportar mayor información.

Comment: Intenta generar el icono de nuevo siguiendo todos los pasos indicados en el apartado [*Cómo crear íconos de selector adaptables y heredados*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/create-app-icons?hl=es-419) en la guía de Android. Al final del proceso, verifica que haya varias carpetas `mipmap` dentro del directorio `res` del tipo `mipmap-hdpi`, `mipmap-mdpi`, etc, cada una de esas carpetas tendrá varios `.xml` que representan el icono generado para cada resolución de pantalla y para cada contexto (aplicación, icono redondo, Google Play, etc).